# Android Studio Webview with Custom CSS (jsoup)

Tags: android, css, webview, jsoup

I want to load **facebook.com** in a webview with custom CSS to change a few things. I use jsoup but everytime i start the app it crashes.

**Here is my code:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.facebook.com").get();
        doc.head().getElementsByTag("link").remove();
        doc.head().appendElement("link").attr("rel", "stylesheet").attr("type", "text/css").attr("href", "style.css");
        String htmlData = doc.outerHtml();
        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(webview);
        webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/.", htmlData, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Logcat output**

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.name.firstapp, PID: 23936
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.name.firstapp/com.example.name.firstapp.MainActivity}:
>   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) Caused
>   by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException at
>   android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
>   at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:431) at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252) at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215) at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
>   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:188)
>   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:157)
>   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:100)
>   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:357)
>   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:340)
>   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
>   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
>   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
>   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114)
>   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
>   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
>   at
>   org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:563)
>   at
>   org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:540)
>   at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:227) at
>   org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:216) at
>   com.example.name.firstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
>   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: @NoumanGhaffar here it is: https://justpaste.it/tqq9

Answer (score 2):

You are connecting to network in the main(UI) thread. So you get android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException.

Android system wont allow that, as it blocks the UI thread. So Use some background threads like AsyncTask or IntentService to access network.

Comment: im completely new to android studio so is there maybe a better solution to load live websites with custom css? @DineshBob

Comment: Jsoup.connect("https://www.facebook.com").get() - connects to the network. Move this line to AsyncTask. http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-basic-jsoup-tutorial/  . Check this link.